# CNContact object save/upload iCloud

Tags: icloud, cloudkit, cncontact, icloud-drive, cncontactstore

This is code to encode [CNContact] array to NSData and upload to iCloud
There are problem is a limit to upload information to iCloud(
Text of error here

```
Error: Optional(<CKError 0x2809b81e0: "Limit Exceeded" (27/2023); server message = "record too large"; op = 0593B55F3FDA20ED; uuid = 7E2C10A5-CC4E-4278-8129-72BCC04D9B2C; container ID = "iCloud.com.own.team.ContactToCloud">)
```

How can I upload/save this type of info to iCloud???

```
func addItem( name: String) {
        allContact = getContact()
         print("allContact \(allContact)")
         do {
             let encodedData : NSData = try! NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: allContact, requiringSecureCoding: true) as NSData
             
             let newContactBook = CKRecord(recordType: "ContactBook")
             newContactBook["data"] = encodedData
             newContactBook["name"] = name
             saveToCloud(record: newContactBook)
         } catch {
             print("error during encoding data\(error)")
         }
      }
```

Comment: Store it as an asset. ie- use the type asset for the field.

Comment: I was used a CNContactVSerialization function to encode/decode data

Comment: It doesn't matter how you convert it, it's too big. Large objects have to go into asset fields.

Comment: You are right! Sometimes I catch an error, that data is too big( Now I need a solution on how to add it into assets! Can you help me with it?

Comment: Look around, there are many examples. The key is that assets can only be loaded from files. So you have to write your object to disk in a temporary file, load the asset, then delete the temp file. When you pull it back, you have to do the reverse.

Comment: OK! Could I load those assets into iCloud?